# Can't upload image from Gallery with request.Addfile on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, restsharp

I'm trying to upload an image from the Gallery got with UIPickerViewController, but using request.Addfile() gets an FileNotFound error. Is there anything wrong on what I am doing or is just impossible to do this way with iOS?

The code is as follows:

```
NSUrl referenceURL = e.Info[new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerReferenceUrl")] as NSUrl;

var request = new RestRequest("account/imageprofile/", Method.POST);
request.AddFile("path_picture",referenceURL.AbsoluteString);
request.AddHeader ("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

client.ExecuteAsync(request, rsResponse)
```

Hope someone can help me with that because I can't find a solution for my problem anywhere..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try reading the file, save it to a personal temp directory and then uploading it.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm 3 years late, but for future reference to those who stumble upon this. Try

```
request.AddFile("path_picture",referenceURL.Path);
```